# Error when creating a list and printing its elements

Tags: c, list

I want to create a list with some additional functions (inserting an additional element at the end, finding a given a element, removing element). Finding a removing works fine, however I have a problem with the list itself (and with the input).

This is my actual code. I have removed a few functions to make it more readable to you.

http://codepad.org/dTGjtYRx

When more elements are created at the beginning of the program or during inserting additional elements the program crashes and gives an error

Thread 1: EXCBADACCESS (code=EXCI386GPFLT)

What is more sometimes when the list is printed 'name' is printed as a weird combination of letters/digits for example -> \360-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
   ListElement *e = malloc(sizeof(Book));
```

should change to that:

```
   ListElement *e = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));
```

also all your arrays should be of size `[51]` to keep the string terminator character.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I haven't realized that there is such a fault in malloc. However I don't get the thing with chars. What is the problem?

Comment: The real string length in 'c' is always one character longer than returned by strlen, because there is a the '\0' terminating character there. When you copy your string with '50' as length check, you really need a 51 char array to accommodate  the max size. you should also make sure that the last element of the array is always '\0'.